# Why is Azure KeyVault getSecret returning Promise <pending>?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-keyvault

I followed the Microsoft tutorial on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-node but I want to have them as separate functions instead of putting them into one main function.

This is what I have, setSecret works fine but getSecret is returning Promise ?

[image: This is the link to the screenshot my code]

Comment: Instead of sharing screenshot of the code, please share the code instead.

Comment: What's the problem for return `Promise<KeyVaultSecret>` ? The SDK offers this method. You wanna find a sync method?

Comment: Obtain key vault secret via rest api is an async method too, I've post the detail below. If you feel my post is of help to you, could you pls pick it as the answer? If  further problems arise, pls feel free to add comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Both `getSecret` and `setSecret` return a `Promise` because they are asynchronous methods that need to make an HTTP request to the Key Vault service.

If you were to try the following:

```
const secretPromise = client.setSecret(secretName, secretValue);
```

You'll notice that `secretPromise` is a `Promise<KeyVaultSecret>` as per the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/@azure/keyvault-secrets/secretclient?view=azure-node-latest#setSecret_string__string__SetSecretOptions_)

This allows you to wait for the secret to be set *and* get back the newly set secret:

```
const secret = await client.setSecret(secretName, secretValue);
```

Be mindful that by not waiting for the `setSecret` call to succeed you will be unable to:

- Get the newly created secret (unless you get lucky with timing)
- Be notified and handle any errors if `setSecret` fails (you can verify this by creating the secret client with an invalid Key Vault URL and running both functions - `azureSetSecret` will claim success but `azureGetSecret` will throw an error)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you are trying to find a way which allows you to obtain key vault secrets in nodejs. As the quick start sample you mentioned above, microsoft provides a async method `await client.getSecret(secretName)` for nodejs.

Here I'd like to recommend you [using rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getkey/getkey) to access key vault secret. When calling the api, you need to generate an access token as the request header, you can refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-nodejs-console) or take a look at my test project below.

calling api:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const auth = require('./credenticalflow');

let vaultName = 'key vault name';
let keyName = 'key name';
let accesstoken = '';
let secret = '';

init();

async function init(){
    const authResponse = await auth.getToken(auth.tokenRequest);
    accesstoken = authResponse.accessToken;
    getsecret(vaultName,keyName,accesstoken);
    console.log("22222222:"+secret);
}

 function getsecret(vaultName,keyName,token){
     console.log('the token is :'+ token);
    axios.get('https://'+vaultName+'.vault.azure.net/secrets/'+keyName+'/7d4b682f5c9a41578602aa5b86611aa7?api-version=7.1',{
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        secret = response.data.value;
        console.log("1111111:"+secret);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log('error');
    });
}
```

generate access token:

```
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');

const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'azure ad app cilent id',
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant name such as xx.onmicrosoft.com>',
        clientSecret: 'client secret for the azure ad app',
    }
};

const tokenRequest = {
    scopes: ['https://vault.azure.net/.default'],
};

const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

async function getToken(tokenRequest) {
    return await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest);
}

module.exports = {
    tokenRequest: tokenRequest,
    getToken: getToken
};
```